How to concatenate multiple columns/fields from CSV to a single string field into Azure Index
I have a CSV in an Azure blob storage.
I created a data source, an index, and an indexer in Azure Search. I can map one-to-one fields from origin to destination, but I want to create a new field in the index that concatenates all text fields from CSV.
How can I achieve this?

please share the code you tried the above question.Please read How to Ask, along with how to create a minimal reproducible example.

Azure AI Search indexers use field mappings to establish the data path between source and destination fields. Implicit mappings occur when field names and data types match, while explicit mappings are defined for cases where they don't match.

Field mappings are added to the fieldMappings array in the indexer definition. Each mapping consists of sourceFieldName, targetFieldName, and optional mappingFunction properties.

Created a sample indexing in Azure AI Search with Azure.Search.Documents client library using NET.





Followed this document to map fields in indexers for Azure AI Search.



Use this document and git for mapping enriched output to fields.

Follow this git for information on how to field map complex types.


